# jSpinner becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I used this code to setup my jspinner with an

- initial value = 8
- minimum = 1
- maximum = 8
- step = 1

```
SpinnerNumberModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(8, 1, 8, 1);
jSpinner2.setModel(sm);
jSpinner2.setValue(1);
```

Initially it loads and changes value to 1. If i click the Up button, the value increases to 2 but then the jspinner becomes unresponsive, not allowing increasing or decreasing. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Without testing this, your code looks okay. So I think the problem might be in the code "around" your JSpinner. Could you please post an [mcve], so we can copy your code to our machines and test it?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: I found the problem. I had copied the JFrame from another project and pasted it into the project. That caused several problems including the unresponsive JSpinner. I created a new JFrame and pasted all of the controls from the faulty JFrame into it. That resolved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. I had copied the JFrame from another project and pasted it into the project. That caused several problems including the unresponsive JSpinner. I created a new JFrame and pasted all of the controls from the faulty JFrame into it. That resolved the problem...